# Prove whether the subgroup of group is always normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This question came in the exam today, unfortunately I couldn't answer it.
The question said:

Proof whether or not this is a true statement, stating the reason.

> Subgroup of group is normal

I have a limited knowledge on group theory, so I couldn't answer this question, also I don't think the question provided enough information.

Comment: Was it asking if the subgroup of a normal group is also normal?

Comment: This is true only if the group is abelian. In the general case is not true always.

Comment: @ xhimi, No, the question didn't say anything about abelian groups

Comment: @xhimi: Not only if. Every subgroup of $Q_8$ is normal but $Q_8$ is not abelian.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Does only if mean if and only if? I meant abelian implies normal :)

Comment: @xhimi: $X$ if $Y$ means $Y \implies X$ whereas $X$ only if $Y$ means $X \implies Y$. What you claimed is that a subgroup is normal only if the group is abelian (i.e. subgroup is normal $\implies$ abelian), but this is false as I pointed out. What is true is that the a subgroup is normal if the group is abelian (i.e. abelain $\implies$ subgroup is normal).